# Issue running anonymous PL/SQL block in MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, mysql-workbench

I understand this is a very naive question, but I am pretty new to MySQL (have use oracle a lot though), and couldn't find a solution anywhere.

I wanted to write a basic anonymous PL/SQL block in workbench but not able to do that, please suggest what needs to be corrected to have this working:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Win64 (x86_64)

Workbench -> 6.3

```
BEGIN
SELECT SYSDATE();
END;
```

Exception:

Error Code: 1064. 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SYSDATE()' at line 2    0.000 sec

when I run `SELECT SYSDATE();` separately, I get the date.

Comment: remove semicolon(;) after END and try

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code you posted. There is no `dbms_output.put_line` in your posted code and in MySQL. Also PL/SQL is Oracle specific. MySQL doesn't understand that. It's got it's own procedural extension.

Comment: in mysql you can only use begin..end blocks in stored programs (procedure,function,triggers,events) -

Comment: @VivekGupta . . . MySQL does not support PL/SQL.  PL/SQL is the scripting language for *the* Oracle database, not for all database products owned by the Oracle company.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Gordon, then how can I write a script on a MYSQL table ?

Comment: Like I have a complex requirement, simple SQL won't work

Comment: @user2042214, tried like that, no luck

Comment: @sticky bit, i was trying using dbms_output.put_line initially, later i changed to even more basic, updated error in my the question above.

Comment: @ P.Salmon, tried stored procedure as well, no luck

Comment: try with wizard means right click on option to create procedure or may be routine and in that write your query.

Comment: Is not supported in MySQL, see [This question] for details.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191521/mysql-how-execute-a-command-block-without-a-procedure-function)