# MySQL how execute a command block without a procedure/function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am try to run a block of SQL commands on MySQL Workbench, like I do on SQL Server, but it is saying me: declare is not valid at this position.

I saw various examples of this on web and I realy do not undertand why this error.

Some tip?

The codes, where the example of SQL Server is ok (running perfectly):

```
MySQL                 | SQL Server
--------------------- | ------------------------
DECLARE A INT;        | DECLARE @A INT;        
DECLARE B INT;        | DECLARE @B INT;        
DECLARE RESULT INT;   | DECLARE @RESULT INT;        
                      |         
BEGIN                 | BEGIN        
  SET A = 1;          |   SET @A = 1;        
  SET B = 2;          |   SET @B = 2;        
  SET RESULT = A + B; |   SET @RESULT = @A + @B;        
END;                  | END;
```

Comment: [DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in MySQL.
You can use `DECLARE` only in compound statements (i.e. within `BEGIN .. END` blocks). Therefore, you can only place such statements in stored procedures, triggers, events and functions.

According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html),

> This section describes the syntax for the BEGIN ... END compound
> statement and other statements that can be used in the body of stored
> programs: Stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events. These
> objects are defined in terms of SQL code that is stored on the server
> for later invocation (see Chapter 20, Stored Programs and Views).
>
> A compound statement is a block that can contain other blocks;
> declarations for variables, condition handlers, and cursors; and flow
> control constructs such as loops and conditional tests.

[Also](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare.html),

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement
> and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Comment: Changing my example putting the declare statements into BEGIN END block the error is the same :( 
Now I have to use Python or C# to resolve a simple problemam, where on SQL Server it will do not be necessary. 
Thanks for the chat ;)

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question is a bit old now but thought I would add the following in case it helps someone else looking at this.

Although DECLARE can only be used in a BEGIN...END statement, you can still use variables in MySql outside of those blocks.

From your example, the following would work in MySql (5.7 in my case):

```
SET @A = 1;
SET @B = 2;
SET @RESULT = @A + @B;

SELECT @RESULT FROM DUAL;
```